# How to replace values between columns based on condition in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe of the form

```
ID              Effective_Date        Paid_Off_Time

xqd27070601     09 August 2016        10 July 2016
xqd21601070     09 September 2016     10 July 2016
xqd26010760     10 July 2016          09 November 2016
```

**EDIT**
Originally, the dates shown are of type String. Their format can be: like this `9/18/2016 16:56`, `09 August 2016`, 9/18/2016. Should we consider converting to timestamp for easier comparison?

**What I want**
if `Effective_Date` > Paid_Off_Time`, replace value of` Effective_Date`with`Paid_Off_Time`and the value of`Paid_Off_Time`with`Effective_Date```.
Basically, switch the values between the 2 columns because the date was insert in the wrong column.

I have thought about using `np.where`, but I am wondering, isn't there a less verbose, cleaner solution?

```
#create a new dataFrame
testDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Effective_Date','Paid_Off_Time'])

#check if Effective_Date < myDataFrame
testDf['Effective_Date'] = np.where(myDataFrame.Effective_Date < myDataFrame.Paid_Off_Time,myDataFrame.Effective_Date,myDataFrame.Paid_Off_Time)

#check if Paid_Off_Time < Effective_Date
testDf['Paid_Off_Time'] = np.where(myDataFrame.Paid_Off_Time < myDataFrame.Effective_Date,myDataFrame.Effective_Date,myDataFrame.Paid_Off_Time)

myDataFrame['Effective_Date'] = testDf[testDf['Effective_Date']]
myDataFrame['Paid_Off_Time'] = testDf[testDf['Paid_Off_Time']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Convert dates to datetime

df=df.assign(Effective_Date=pd.to_datetime(df['Effective_Date'], format='%d %B %Y'),Paid_Off_Time=pd.to_datetime(df['Paid_Off_Time'], format='%d %B %Y'))
```

Select as per condition

```
m=df.Effective_Date>df.Paid_Off_Time
```

Swap values if condition met

```
 df.loc[m, ['Effective_Date','Paid_Off_Time']]=df.loc[m, ['Paid_Off_Time','Effective_Date']].values#Swap rows if condition met
    print(df)



  ID     Effective_Date Paid_Off_Time
0  xqd27070601     09 August 2016  10 July 2016
1  xqd21601070  09 September 2016  10 July 2016
2  xqd26010760   09 November 2016  10 July 2016
```

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: It's pandas  1.0.1

Comment: Why don't we convert dates to timeStamp so that we can compare easier.

Comment: What does ```m``` stand for in ```m=df.Effective_Date>df.Paid_Off_Time```

Comment: On pandas 1.0.1 . The dates get converted to a format that they can be compared. Didnt know you had a preference of date formats. m is a bolean selection which results from the comparison of the dates. That boolean is then used alongside the.loc accessor to call the affected rows

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: The problem is that the dates in my actual file are formatted as: ```10/07/2016 09:00``` or ```9/14/2016 19:31``` or ```10/07/2016```, so I would need to apply a condition in the formatter, but I don't know how.

Comment: This are not the dates you provided in the question are they? Can you edit the question? Usually, you would at least upvote the answer and then seek to add information and ask for help.

Comment: @wwnde I get ```KeyError: ('Paid_Off_Time', 'Effective_Date')```

Comment: Key means the fields are wrong. It could be because our fields are named slightly different. Usually I run df.columns. I then copy each individual  column from the output. That way if there are spaces or difference I cant see, they are taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sorting values in numpy to improve performance:

```
df['Effective_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Effective_Date'])
df['Paid_Off_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Paid_Off_Time'])

c = ['Effective_Date','Paid_Off_Time']
data = np.sort(myDataFrame[c].to_numpy(), axis=1)
myDataFrame[c] = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=c)
print (myDataFrame)
            ID Effective_Date Paid_Off_Time
0  xqd27070601     2016-07-10    2016-08-09
1  xqd21601070     2016-07-10    2016-09-09
2  xqd26010760     2016-07-10    2016-11-09
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing a piece of my project code in which i did somewhat similar thing, I hope this kind of implementation will give you the solution.

```
df['Effective_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Effective_date'], format= '%d/%m/%Y')
df['Paid_Off_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Paid_Off_Time'], format= '%d/%m/%Y')
for i in range(0,len(df))
  if df['Effective_Date'][i]>df['Paid_Off_Time'][i]:
    k=df['Effective_Date'][i]
    df['Effective_Date'][i]=df['Paid_Off_Time'][i]
    df['Paid_Off_Time'][i]=k
```